# How to use HTML DOM elemets in alloyui dataTable

Tags: javascript, alloy-ui

I want to show `DOM` elements in `alloyui` `dataTable`. but the `alloyui` table does not show the `DOM` elements. My code is as following:

```
var tableData = [];
        this._popupContent.innerHTML = "";
        for(var key in this._info){
              (function(k) {
                var item = {};
                item.name = k;
                item.dom = document.createElement('a');
                item.dom.innerHTML = key;
                item.dom.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    //do something
                    console.log(k);
                });
                tableData.push(item);
            })(key)
        }

        YUI().use(
            'aui-datatable',
            function(Y) {
            var columns = [
                {   key:        'name',
                    allowHTML:  true
                },
                {
                    key: 'dom',
                    allowHTML: true
                }
            ];
            new Y.DataTable({
                    columnset: columns,
                    recordset: tableData
                }).render('#popupContent');
            }
        );
```

can some help me?